# Knockout Js to Dynamic(Based on user Selection) disable past date in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I, have use the Bootstrap DatePicker to use the calender. I, have two input box in table with multiple rows. In, each row the user can select start date and end date. Default value of start Date is new Date(). I, have disable the pass date on first load of the screen. I, have a requirement of disable the pass dates based on the user selection.

Here is the Html Code

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: responseUserSetUpData().userListViewModel">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: SelectedUser, visible: !SelectedUser">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span></td>
                                        <td><select class= "form-control" data-bind="options: Roles,optionsText: 'Name',value: SelectedRoleId,optionsValue:'Id',optionsCaption: '-- Select Role --'"></select></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="datepicker form-control"  data-bind="datePicker: ko.observable(new Date(FormatStartDate)) , textInput : FormatStartDate , attr: {id: UserId}, datePickerOptions: {startDate: new Date()}"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" data-bind="datePicker: ko.observable(new Date(FormatEndDate)), textInput: FormatEndDate , attr :{id: UserId}, datePickerOptions: {startDate: new Date(FormatStartDate)}" ></td>
                                    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Custom Knockout Binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datePicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var unwrap = ko.utils.unwrapObservable;
            var dataSource = valueAccessor();
            var binding = allBindingsAccessor();
            var options = {
                keyboardNavigation: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                //startDate: userManagementVM.StartMeetingDate()
            };
            if (binding.datePickerOptions) {
                options = $.extend(options, binding.datePickerOptions);
            }
            $(element).datepicker(options);
            $(element).datepicker('update', dataSource());
            $(element).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                if ($(element).is(':focus')) {
                    $(element).one('blur', function (ev) {
                        var dateVal = $(element).datepicker("getDate");
                        observable(dateVal);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    observable(ev.date);
                }
            });
            //handle removing an element from the dom
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).datepicker('remove');
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).datepicker('update', value);
        }
    };
```

Screen Shot of the UI

[image: date picker issue]

The existing code only disable on first load of the screen. However when user change the value it doesn't disable on the new date selected value.

Can please anyone let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: You would need some kind of mechanism to let the control know of the date changed event on the other control...One way that I can think of is wrapping your datepicker control under a Boolean observable and subscribe to your date value. On the subsription handler, change and revert the value of the Boolean so that it will recreate the control with the updated value of the start/end date...

Comment: @gkb - I understand your point. Can you please show me with some code.. Thank you